# passing a variable to QTableWidget Delegate in createEditor QT

Tags: qt, delegates, qtablewidget

My custom delegate item (item of a QTableWidget) need to know a variable from the parent dialog
How I can retrieve it?

```
QWidget* CustomDelegate::createEditor ( QWidget* parent , const QStyleOptionViewItem& option , const QModelIndex& index ) const
{
    QWidget* delegate = QItemDelegate::createEditor(parent, option, index);
    if(index.column() == 1)
    {
        QDoubleSpinBox* spin = new QDoubleSpinBox(parent);
        spin->setDecimals(1);
        ...
    }
    else if(index.column() == 2)
    {
        if (???VARIABLE FROM PARENT DIALOG???)
        {
            QLineEdit* timeObj = new QLineEdit(parent);
            timeObj->setInputMask("99");
            QRegExp rx("[0-9\\s][0-9\\s]");
            QValidator *myvalidat = new QRegExpValidator(rx, 0);
            timeObj->setValidator(myvalidat);
            return timeObj;
        }
        QLineEdit* timeObj = new QLineEdit(parent);
        timeObj->setInputMask("99:99");
        ....
    }
}
else
    return delegate;
```

Comment: What is the `parent dialog`?

Comment: the customdelegate is a delegate of a QTableWidget. The QTableWidget is a widget inside a QMainWindow, this QMainWindow has the member variable

Comment: You might simply pass that pointer to the `CustomDelegate` constructor and store it as a member variable?

Comment: ..Yeah.. simple and effective.. I don't know how I can't get it. Thank you Vahancho